# How to Order Data Query in Entity Framework Table Relationships LINQ Method syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-method-syntax

I am having a problem ordering data by table **Iscinstances** row **Name** in table relationships, the **Iscinstances** table is *JOIN* in **LinkUsersToIscinstances** table, below is my query for the table relationships.

The problem is that **OrderBy** *a.LinkUsersToIscinstances.Iscinstances.Name* is an error, how to fix the order query ?

```
var customer = await _context.Users
                            .Where(c => c.UserId  == UserId && c.LastActivityDate > date && c.IsApproved == num)
                            .Include(c => c.Profile)
                            .Include(a => a.LinkUsersToIscinstances).ThenInclude(b => b.Iscinstances)
                            .OrderBy(a => a.LinkUsersToIscinstances.Iscinstances.Name).ThenBy(c => c.LastName).ThenBy(c => c.FirstName)
                            .ToListAsync();
```

I am trying to order data by table row name in table relationships, I want to get the query to order them by table **Iscinstances** *Name*, table  **Users** *LastName*, table  **Users** *FirstName*

This are my classis table relationships

```
UserProfile

    public virtual ICollection<LinkUsersToIscinstance> LinkUsersToIscinstances { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

LinkUsersToIscinstance

```
    public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual Iscinstance Iscinstances { get; set; }
    public virtual User Users { get; set; }
```

Iscinstance

```
    public virtual ICollection<LinkUsersToIscinstance> LinkUsersToIscinstances { get; set; }
```

User

```
    public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LinkUsersToIscinstance> LinkUsersToIscinstances { get; set; }
```

Comment: "OrderBy a.LinkUsersToIscinstances.Iscinstances.Name is an error" is it? what error?

Comment: I cannot understand how do you plan to order by `LinkUsersToIscinstances` navigation property with is a collection property. Looks like a nonsense.

Comment: its not ordering them by `LinkUsersToIscinstances`, its ordering them by `Iscinstances` row `Name`, table  `Iscinstances` is JOIN in `LinkUsersToIscinstances` table relationship, so if you just also put `a.Iscinstances.Name` it will be an error @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: `ICollection<LinkUsersToIscinstances> does not contain a definition for Iscinstances and no extention method Iscinstances acception the first argument type` is the error @JeremyLakeman

Comment: Nothing changed after your comment. `LinkUsersToIscinstances` is a collection and you want to Order by ALL items in this collection even you want to order by `Iscinstances.Name`, which is also wrong because `Iscinstances` is also collection.  What you can do is order by first item in collection.

Comment: I'll update the post and include my classic relationships @JeremyLakeman

Comment: All what you can do here, only order by first item `.OrderBy(a => a.LinkUsersToIscinstances.FirstOrDefault().Iscinstances.Name)…`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it is not actually working because it is only selecting top 1 form Name by order

Comment: How to order by a collection of objects - this is the question that you have to answer for yourself. Or better write SQL which do needed order and we can understand then. But, it should be a case, and you want to just order `LinkUsersToIscinstances` in result?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv very sorry for my english if you did not understand but I want it like this, this output of `LinkUsersToIscinstance ` `"LinkUsersToIscinstance ": [ { ...         "iscinstance": [ { ... } ]     } ]` inside the `LinkUsersToIscinstance ` will list all the data from `iscinstance` right?, i want it to be order the list of `iscinstance` data by Name

Comment: old EF6 or new EF Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query.

```cs
var customer = await _context.Users
    .Where(c => c.UserId  == UserId && c.LastActivityDate > date && c.IsApproved == num)
    .Include(c => c.Profile)
    .Include(a => a.LinkUsersToIscinstances.OrderBy(x => x.Iscinstances.Name)).ThenInclude(b => b.Iscinstances)
    .OrderBy(c => c.LastName).ThenBy(c => c.FirstName)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: it work if I don't include the `Select` method but in my case now I included `Select` method I have put the `.OrderBy(x => x.Iscinstances.Name)` or `.OrderBy(x => x.Name)` inside the `Select` method , thanks for helping me out, really appreciate your help I can use this method on my other query that don't include `Select` method

Comment: Remember that `Select` and `Include` two mutual exclusive operators, that's why after `Select` your ordering and Includes are discarded.